# I am unable to get the value mapped to a react native Button from onPress, it returns undefined when updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I mapped through an array and set the value and title of the Button component. The title and of the react native Button is rendered correctly and is displayed as expected.

```
{fetchedData.map((fetched)=>{
          return(
            <Button title={fetched.PropertyName} value={fetched.PropertyName} onPress={handlePress} />
          )
        })}
```

When handling onPress function I try to update the context of the app:

```
import {PropertyContext} from '../context/PropertyContext'
const {property, setProperty} = useContext(PropertyContext);
const handlePress = async (e) =>{
       await setProperty(e.target.value); //e.target.title doesn't work either
        alert(property, "selected");
        navigation.navigate('Welcome');
    }
```

The e.target.value and e.target.title always return undefined.

Here is the created context as well:

```
import  {createContext} from "react";
export const PropertyContext =  createContext({property: null})
export default PropertyContext;
```

Comment: check the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike on the web, `onPress` doesn't dispatch event-related data.

Refactor code as below:

```js
const handlePress = async (fetched) => {
  // Use fetched data as per your app flow
  console.log(fetched);
};

{
  fetchedData.map((fetched) => {
    return (
      <Button
        title={fetched.PropertyName}
        value={fetched.PropertyName}
        onPress={() => handlePress(fetched)}
      />
    );
  });
}
```